# Touchpad scroll direction

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

When using a touchpad mouse connected to an Android device via Bluetooth, is is possible to invert the scroll direction when using two fingers on the touchpad?

By default, it works like "natural scrolling", where moving your fingers down on the touchpad causes content to scroll up.    I prefer content to scroll down as I move my fingers down.